# Changing and altering ranges of x and y axis in a line graph in MatplotLib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, linegraph

[image]
[image]

I have created a line graph in Image 1 while I want to change my x-axis which is the 365 days of a year to 12 months but need to plot values of each date. I want to develop a graph like 2. 
My  Dataframe looks like this

```
       Month       Date   max   min
0      1.0 1900-01-01  15.6 -16.0
1      1.0 1900-01-02  13.9 -26.7
2      1.0 1900-01-03  13.3 -26.7
3      1.0 1900-01-04  10.6 -26.1
4      1.0 1900-01-05  12.8 -15.5
```

Comment: use resample documentation in the link 

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score 0):

Without the code and a try, we can't provide you with a fix.
However, using MatplotLib, the function you are looking for is:

- [xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

An example that should help you provided by the documentation:

```
 xticks(np.arange(5), ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue'))

# np.arange(5) is the location, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
# ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue') are the labels
```

*EDIT:* since you're dataframe stores data, you can make a dictionnary to convert number to month:

```
month = {1: "January", 2: "February", ..., 12: "December"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use resampling for this purpose, do a:

```
df=df.resample("M").last() # M stands for monoth, you can do w for weeks etc
#also .last() will take the last entry of the month
```

instead of .last() you can also use number of other ways as well, like .min() .max() .mean() etc which will take the values accordingly

documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)